# select2 multi group select. Select parent, disable child nodes. Unselect parent, enable child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I have implemented 2 custom functions with `select2`:

1. Select parent node, add parent node to selected and disable child nodes.
2. Unselect parent node, remove from selected and enable child nodes.

This is working, except when adding and removing parent node in this order:

1. Select parent
2. Open emerging options (you can see child nodes are disabled)
3. Click outside search box, so emerging options close
4. Unselect parent
5. Open emerging box again (child nodes are still disabled)

On the contrary, it works if step 2 and 3 are not done.

1. Select parent
2. Unselect parent
3. Open emerging options (you can see child nodes are enabled back)

Please see a working example:

```js
const tags = [{
    'id': 1,
    'text': 'Parent 1',
    'children': [{
        'id': 'tag11',
        'text': 'Tag 11'
      },
      {
        'id': 'tag12',
        'text': 'Tag 12'
      }, {
        'id': 'parent1',
        'text': 'Parent 1'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'text': 'Parent 2',
    'children': [{
        'id': 'tag21',
        'text': 'Tag 21'
      },
      {
        'id': 'tag22',
        'text': 'Tag 22'
      },
      {
        'id': 'parent2',
        'text': 'Parent 2'
      },
    ],
  }
];
$(document).ready(function() {

  const selectField = $('#target');
  
  selectField.select2({
    width: '300px',
    templateResult: function(option) {
      if (option.element && (option.element).hasAttribute('hidden')) {
        return null;
      }
      return option.text;
    }
  });

  selectField.on('select2:open', function(e) {
    let allOptionsStart = this.options;
    $('#select2-target-results').on('click', function(event) {
      let allOptions = [];
      $.each(allOptionsStart, (key, option) => {
        allOptions[option.value] = option;
      });

      const data = $(event.target).html();
      const selectedOptionGroup = data.toString().trim();

      let selectedOptionGroupId = '';
      $.each(tags, (key, tag) => {
        if (selectedOptionGroup.toString() === tag.text.toString()) {
          $.each(tag.children, (key, child) => {
            if (selectedOptionGroup.toString() === child.text) {
              selectedOptionGroupId = child.id;
            }
            const jTag = $(allOptions[child.id]);
            if (Object.keys(jTag).length > 0) {
              if (!jTag[0].hidden) {
                jTag[0].disabled = true;
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
      $('select').select2({
        width: '300px',
        templateResult: function(option) {
          if (option.element && (option.element).hasAttribute('hidden')) {
            return null;
          }
          return option.text;
        }
      });
      event.stopPropagation();

      let options = selectField.val();
      if (options === null || options === '') {
        options = [];
      }
      options.push(selectedOptionGroupId);

      selectField.val(options);
      selectField.trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
      selectField.select2('close');
    });
  });

  selectField.on('select2:unselecting', function(e) {
    let allOptions = [];
    $.each(this.options, (key, option) => {
      allOptions[option.value] = option;
    });
    const unselectedGroupText = e.params.args.data.text;
    $.each(tags, (key, tag) => {
      if (unselectedGroupText === tag.text) {
        $.each(tag.children, (key, childTag) => {
          const jTag = $(allOptions[childTag.id]);
          if (Object.keys(jTag).length > 0) {
            if (!jTag[0].hidden) {
              jTag[0].disabled = false;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
li.select2-results__option strong.select2-results__group:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="target" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple='multiple'>
  <optgroup label="Parent 1">
    <option value="tag11">Tag 11</option>
    <option value="tag12">Tag 12</option>
    <option value="parent1" hidden>Parent 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Parent 2">
    <option class="tag21">Tag 21</option>
    <option class="tag22">Tag 22</option>
    <option value="parent2" hidden>Parent 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

jsfiddle (just in case): https://jsfiddle.net/ivantxo/bzu2xmp9/151/

Can anyone please help me to see what's wrong?

This should work in both cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE instead of an external link

Comment: @mplungjan I have added a reproducible piece of code (minimal). Thanks

Comment: Why not make a snippet? I showed you how. They run just as well as in jsfiddle except when using localStorage which is not allowed here

Comment: Wow. So complicated. You need to decide if the text of the unselected tag contains parent and then set disabled to false for all of them in this loop: `$.each(tag.children, (key, childTag) => {
          const jTag = $(allOptions[childTag.id]);
          if (Object.keys(jTag).length > 0) {
            if (!jTag[0].hidden) {
              jTag[0].disabled = false;
            }
          }
        });`

Comment: @mplungjan That is not correct since I am already doing that. Have a look in the snippet at the selectField.on('select2:unselecting', function(e) method.

Comment: I know you are. But it is there you ALSO need to loop and set disabled to false for the OTHER entries

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add some classes to the options, to make identification easier.

I placed the [select2](https://select2.org/) plugin assignment in a function, to facilitate reuse, as in this implementation, the [select2 destroy method](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control) will be used to reapply the plugin and update the display.

I used click monitoring in the optgroups in a [delegated](https://api.jquery.com/on/) way, for practical reasons. When the click event occurs, it compares the label of the select2 component with the label of the `optgroup`, to disable and remove the selection of child options with the optnormal class, in addition to selecting the `option` with the opthidden class.

`selectField.on('select2:unselecting', function(e) {` allows you to find out which element was removed from the selection with `e.params.args.data.element`, simply checking if it is the option with the opthidden class to fetch the parent `optgroup` and re-enable the child options with the optnormal class.

```js
const selectField = $('#target');

const setSelect2 = function() {
  selectField.select2({
    width: '300px',
    templateResult: function(option) {
      if (option.element && (option.element).hasAttribute('hidden')) {
        return null;
      }
      return option.text;
    }
  });
};

setSelect2();

$(document.body).on('click', '.select2-results__option', function() {
  var label = $(this).find('.select2-results__group').html();
  $('optgroup.optgroup').each(function() {
    if (this.label === label) {
      $(this).find('option.optnormal').prop({
        'disabled': true,
        'selected': false
      });
      $(this).find('option.opthidden').prop('selected', true);
    }
  });

  selectField.select2('destroy');
  setSelect2();
});

selectField.on('select2:unselecting', function(e) {
  var $option = $(e.params.args.data.element);
  if ($option.hasClass('opthidden')) {
    $option.parents('optgroup').find('option.optnormal').prop('disabled', false);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      selectField.select2('close');
      selectField.select2('destroy');
      setSelect2();
      selectField.select2('open');
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
li.select2-results__option strong.select2-results__group:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="target" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple='multiple'>
  <optgroup label="Parent 1" class="optgroup">
    <option value="tag11" class="optnormal">Tag 11</option>
    <option value="tag12" class="optnormal">Tag 12</option>
    <option value="parent1" hidden class="opthidden">Parent 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Parent 2" class="optgroup">
    <option value="tag21" class="optnormal">Tag 21</option>
    <option value="tag22" class="optnormal">Tag 22</option>
    <option value="parent2" hidden class="opthidden">Parent 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be trying this on the weekend and see how it goes.

Comment: I believe this is more succinct than the other answer. This worked for me and I implemented this strategy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this much. I hope it will be helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select2 Example</title>
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        
        .parent {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .child {
            margin-left: 20px;
            color: #888;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" multiple style="width: 300px;">
        <optgroup label="Parent 1" class="parent">
            <option value="parent1">Parent 1</option>
            <option value="child1_1" class="child" data-parent="parent1">Child 1.1</option>
            <option value="child1_2" class="child" data-parent="parent1">Child 1.2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Parent 2" class="parent">
            <option value="parent2">Parent 2</option>
            <option value="child2_1" class="child" data-parent="parent2">Child 2.1</option>
            <option value="child2_2" class="child" data-parent="parent2">Child 2.2</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Initialize Select2
            $('#mySelect').select2();

            // Listen for changes on the parent options
            $('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
                var selectedOptions = $(this).val();

                // Track selected parents and children
                var selectedParents = [];
                var selectedChildren = [];

                // Iterate through selected options
                $.each(selectedOptions, function(index, value) {
                    // Check if the selected option is a parent
                    if (value.startsWith('parent')) {
                        selectedParents.push(value);
                    } else {
                        selectedChildren.push(value);
                    }
                });

                // Deselect any child options associated with selected parents
                $.each(selectedParents, function(index, parentValue) {
                    $.each(selectedChildren, function(index, childValue) {
                        var childOption = $('.child[data-parent="' + parentValue + '"][value="' + childValue + '"]');
                        if (childOption.length > 0) {
                            childOption.prop('selected', false);
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Disable child options associated with selected parents
                $('.child').prop('disabled', false); // Enable all child options
                $.each(selectedParents, function(index, parentValue) {
                    $('.child[data-parent="' + parentValue + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
                });

                // Trigger Select2 change event to refresh the UI
                $('#mySelect').trigger('change.select2');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be trying this on the weekend and see how it goes.

Comment: This also works but it was missing hidding the parent from the child list. This is why I chose the other as the correct answer. But this works too. Thank you